# Overusing html section element

Tags: html

Trying to figure out proper usage of the html5 `<section>` element. Am I overusing the `<section>` element in this instance?

```
<main>
    <section id="slider">
        <h2>What we can do</h2><!-- not visible -->
        <section>
            <h3>Slider 1</h3>
            <p>description</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Slider 2</h3>
            <p>description</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Slider 3</h3>
            <p>description</p>
        </section>  
    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>Our mission</h2><!-- not visible -->
        <section>
            <h3>Grow</h3>
            <p>description</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Big Ideas</h3>
            <p>description</p>
        </section>
        <section>
            <h3>Latest Trends</h3>
            <p>description</p>
        </section>
    </section>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

**MDN** has an example using it the same way so it looks like you are using it correctly. So long as those are all an outline of your site then semantically it makes sense to use **section** over **div**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Sections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FHTML%2FSections_and_Outlines_of_an_HTML5_document#The_HTML5_Outline_Algorithm

Comment: [Impressive Webs](http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-section/) state "DO use section for each individual section of a tab switcher or **content slider** (if an unordered list isn’t needed)"

Comment: @Larry21 What you have in not a good place for divs. Sections would definitely be a better choice. These are not generic elements, they are content pieces. A div is only now used for places in a layout that just have no meaning to the content document.

Comment: @Larry21 I would trust the Mozilla Developer Network over Louis Lazaris especially since Mr. Lazaris can't seem to make up his mind in his own blog post.

Comment: @jeff_kile - The difficulty here is not over what MDN says (which is fine), but your interpretation of it, by asserting that the inner `<section>`s in the question are generic containers.

Comment: @Larry21 You're right, I did some more research and MDN does use section like div one defining an outline, I changed my answer.